# kivy cant load image in requesturl android

Tags: python, kivy

I want to get images from my site using UrlRequest and API to display them in Kivy. this code
The codes I wrote work correctly in Windows and Linux, but in Android it gives me a black picture. In fact, it cannot load the photo

this is my codes:

home_page.py:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest


class HomePage(MDScreen):

    def on_enter(self):
        self.free_courses()

    def free_courses(self):
            data = UrlRequest('my api')
            data.wait(delay=0.5)
            for course in data.result:
                self.ids.free_courses.add_widget(FreeCourses(
                    image=course.get('app_image'),
                    title=course.get('category_name')))
```

home_page.kv:

```
<FreeCourses>
    size_hint: None, None

    MDRelativeLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 100
        FitImage:
            source: root.image
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 80
            radius: [10,]
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
```

in windows or linux:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqIsO.png)

but in android:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDZF.png)